# Weird TeX syntax highlighting issue

Tags: auctex, display

I running Emacs 25 on Debian 9.0 stretch. The version is `25.1+1-4+deb9u1`.

I have a local copy of AUCTeX installed via Melpa. The relevant line in `M-x list-packages` is:

```
auctex           11.88.3       installed       Integrated environment for *TeX*
```

See the screenshot below. The text

```
\url\expandafter{\
```

in the macro `\PrintDocTable` is highlighted in brown and is a larger size for no apparent reason. This is also messing up bracket matching, which is really what bought it to my attention. For me, this falls into the trivial bug aggravating category.

Suggestions to debug are appreciated.

1. If I copy this to another file, this issue disappears.
2. Copying between buffers in emacs also makes the issue disappear.
3. Running `M-x latex-mode` also makes the issue disappear, but it
   reappears on re-opening the file.

[image]

Comment: can you post the actual text shown in your screenshot? It would make it easier to reproduce the problem - we can't copy and paste from your image

Comment: @Tyler Excellent point - I didn't think of that. Will do that now. Would a gist-paste be good, or should I include the entire text into the question? It's quite long. Or should I do both?

Comment: I could also post my `.emacs` if that is helpful.

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX are you using?  And how did you install it?

Comment: For some reason, it looks like I don't have the Debian AUCTeX installed. So it might be a local install. Assuming I'm using the Emacs package manager, how can I find this out?

Comment: Do `M-x list-packages RET` and and search for AUCTeX in the `*Packages*` buffer.

Comment: @ArashEsbati 11.88.3. See the update to my question. It seems melpa doesn't do automated updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of AUCTeX, your example looks like this for me:

[image]

`url` command looks for its argument in braces (`\url{arg}`) or in delimiters (`\url|arg|`).  In your case, it takes `\` as the delimiter and fontifies everything until next `\`, i.e. `expandafter{`.

I suggest you update your AUCTeX installation via ELPA.  But even with the updated version, the fontification will not match your expectation.  AUCTeX doesn't parse your document in order to see and understand the `\expandafter`.

The brace matching confusion is also a result of the fontification (aka syntax highlighting): Within `\url\expandafter{\`, `{` is not treated as an opening brace, but as ordinary text.  Hence the behavior you observe.

You can turn off fontification (aka syntax highlighting) in your `.sty` file with <kbd>M-x font-lock-mode RET</kbd> which will restore the correct parsing of braces.  I wouldn't consider this a bug: AUCTeX is optimized for writing LaTeX files and not hacking `.sty` files.

Comment: I think I'm missing the implications of your answer. Are you saying you are seeing similar syntax to what I'm seeing. But does it mess up bracket matching? And is my AUCTeX version a problem or not?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - See my updated answer.

Comment: The fontification isn't a problem per se. But the bracket matching getting screwed up is. And why does this fontification come and go? Are you seeing any problems with bracket matching?

Comment: And I did the AUCTeX upgrade, but I'm still seeing the bracket matching problem.

Comment: I could post another image of the bracket matching issue, if that would help.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - See next update.

Comment: So, to be clear, you are saying the bracket issue is unavoidable? And what is doing this fontification? Is it AUCTeX? And, regardless, is it possible to turn it off? And also, could this be considered a bug? And if so, where?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - See next round of update.

Comment: Actually, running `M-x latex mode` gets rid of the issue, though I have no idea why.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - It turns off AUCTeX's syntax highlighting (among other things).

Comment: Oh, does it? That would explain it, then.